# How to run this statement multiple times and put them in a matrix?

Tags: export, iterators, infinite-loop, procedural-programming

I have the following Mathematica Code.

```
QueProcess = QueueingProcess[\[Lambda], \[Mu], c, c];
Simplify[QueueProperties[QueProcess], c > 0 && c \[Element] Integers];
NumReq = RandomFunction[QueProcess /. {\[Lambda] -> 1, \[Mu] -> 2, c -> 10}, {0, 9999, 
    1}];
Val = NumReq["Values"];
```

Note that `Val` contains 10000 elements.

Now I want to generate a matrix of size 100 X 10000. That is I want to run the following

```
NumReq = RandomFunction[QueProcess /. {\[Lambda] -> 1, \[Mu] -> 2, c -> 10}, {0, 9999, 
        1}];
Val = NumReq["Values"];
```

100 times and save the values of each realization as a row in the matrix.

Finally, I need to export to matrix as `.mat` format to use it in Matlab.

Any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use Table with an index for Val (I changed 9999 to 99 to make things faster):

```
 Table[NumReq = 
  RandomFunction[
   QueProcess /. {λ -> 1, μ -> 2, c -> 10}, {0, 99, 1}];
 Val[k] = NumReq["Values"], {k, 1, 100}]
```

Then Use Table again to get the Val Matrix as an assembly of Rows.

```
Valmat = Table[Val[k], {k, 1, 100}]
```

You get the Expected dimensions for Valmat

```
In[15]:= Dimensions[Valmat]

Out[15]= {100, 100}
```

Export should work also:

```
Export["valmat.mat", Valmat]
```

(I did not check the contents of valmat.mat in Matlab though)

Hope this helps !

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not working for me! When I find the dimension , it just gives {100} and gives an error message "Export::type: {{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,<<9951>>}[1],{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,<<9951>>}[2],<<48>>,<<50>>} cannot be exported to the MAT format."

Comment: I think the second statement is not needed. I mean "Valmat = Table[Val[k], {k, 1, 100}]" is not required.

Comment: The code works fine for me without any errors. Which Mathematica version are you on ? Can you try quitting kernel and then running the code again ?